# need to set and read a cookie using Perl

Tags: perl, cookies

I an trying to add setting a cookie, and reading it to an existing Perl script. I found example code at https://alvinalexander.com/perl/edu/articles/pl010012/ and indeed the 2 example scripts work, when run by themselves. So I tried to set up functions to use these in my existing script. Here they are

```
sub set_cookie
{
#------------------------------#
#  1. Create a new CGI object  #
#------------------------------#

my $session = shift;

my $query;
my $cookie;
my $cookie1;
my $cookie2;
my $theCookie;
my $val;
my $id;


$query = new CGI;

logit("Entering set_cookie() called with $session\n");

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
#  2. Create the desired cookie using the cookie() method.
#     Do this before calling the header() method, because the cookie must be
#     incorporated into the HTTP header.
#
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------#

$val = "Session_ID=$session";
logit("Cookie val set to $val\n");

$cookie = $query->cookie(-name=>'MY_COOKIE',
                         -value=>$val,
                         -expires=>'+10m',
                         -path=>'/');

$cookie1 = CGI::Cookie->new(-name=>'ID',
                                -expires=>'+10m',
                                -value=>123456);


$cookie2 = CGI::Cookie->new(-name=>'preferences',
                           -value=>{ font => 'Helvetica',
                                     size => 12 }
                           );

print header(-cookie=>[$cookie1,$cookie2]);

my %cookies = CGI::Cookie->fetch;
$id = $cookies{'ID'}->value;

logit("Cookie id set to $id\n");
logit("Cookie val set to $val\n");

#--------------------------------------------------------------#
#  3. Create the HTTP header and print the doctype statement.  #
#--------------------------------------------------------------#

print $query->header(-cookie => $cookie);
$theCookie = $query->cookie('MY_COOKIE');
print $query->end_html;sub read_cookie
{
#------------------------------#
#  1. Create a new CGI object  #
#------------------------------#

my $rval = 0;
my $theCookie ='';
my $name;
my $string;

my $query = new CGI;

logit("Entering read_cookie()\n");

#--------------------------------------------------------------#
#  2. Create the HTTP header and print the doctype statement.  #
#--------------------------------------------------------------#

print $query->header;


#----------------------------------------------------#
#  3. Start the HTML doc, and give the page a title  #
#----------------------------------------------------#

print $query->start_html('My cookie-get.cgi program');


#----------------------------------------------------------------------#
#  4. Retrieve the cookie. Do this by using the cookie method without  #
#     the -value parameter.                                            #
#----------------------------------------------------------------------#


# print $query->h3('The cookie is ...');
$theCookie = $query->cookie('MY_COOKIE');

if(!$theCookie) {
        $theCookie = '';
}

# logit("theCookie = $theCookie\n");
if (index($theCookie, 'ID') != -1) {
        $rval = 1;
}


logit("read_cookie() returning rval = $rval. Having read a value of $theCookie\n");
print $query->end_html;
return($rval);
}
```

But this does not work. I've looked at the samples and it seems that set_cookie script sends the set-cookie before declaring the HTML header, which does not seem correct to me. I call these like this

```
if (!read_cookie()) {        #get the session id for later use
        $id = $session{_session_id};
#       print "\n\nSession ID $id\n";
        set_cookie($id);
        return($id);
}
# I would GREATLY appreciate some guidance here as my frustration level is very high
         $session_id = start_session($cgi);
}
 # and start_sessions calls set_cookie
```

Comment: `$id = $session{_session_id};` where is the `%session` hash defined?

Comment: my $id;
        my %session;

        tie %session, 'Apache::Session::Postgres', $id, {
             Handle => $dbh
         };

Comment: `$session_id = start_session($cgi)` where is `start_session()` defined?