# How I get session

Tags: perl, cookies

I an trying to add setting a cookie, and reading it to an existing Perl script. I found example code at https://alvinalexander.com/perl/edu/articles/pl010012/ and indeed the 2 example scripts work, when run by themselves. So I tried to set up functions to use these in my existing script. Here they are

```
sub set_cookie
{
#------------------------------#
#  1. Create a new CGI object  #
#------------------------------#

my $session = shift;

my $query;
my $cookie;
my $cookie1;
my $cookie2;
my $theCookie;
my $val;
my $id;


$query = new CGI;

logit("Entering set_cookie() called with $session\n");

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
#  2. Create the desired cookie using the cookie() method.
#     Do this before calling the header() method, because the cookie must be
#     incorporated into the HTTP header.
#
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------#

$val = "Session_ID=$session";
logit("Cookie val set to $val\n");

$cookie = $query->cookie(-name=>'MY_COOKIE',
                         -value=>$val,
                         -expires=>'+10m',
                         -path=>'/');

$cookie1 = CGI::Cookie->new(-name=>'ID',
                                -expires=>'+10m',
                                -value=>123456);


$cookie2 = CGI::Cookie->new(-name=>'preferences',
                           -value=>{ font => 'Helvetica',
                                     size => 12 }
                           );

print header(-cookie=>[$cookie1,$cookie2]);

my %cookies = CGI::Cookie->fetch;
$id = $cookies{'ID'}->value;

logit("Cookie id set to $id\n");
logit("Cookie val set to $val\n");

#--------------------------------------------------------------#
#  3. Create the HTTP header and print the doctype statement.  #
#--------------------------------------------------------------#

print $query->header(-cookie => $cookie);
$theCookie = $query->cookie('MY_COOKIE');
print $query->end_html;sub read_cookie
{
#------------------------------#
#  1. Create a new CGI object  #
#------------------------------#

my $rval = 0;
my $theCookie ='';
my $name;
my $string;

my $query = new CGI;

logit("Entering read_cookie()\n");

#--------------------------------------------------------------#
#  2. Create the HTTP header and print the doctype statement.  #
#--------------------------------------------------------------#

print $query->header;


#----------------------------------------------------#
#  3. Start the HTML doc, and give the page a title  #
#----------------------------------------------------#

print $query->start_html('My cookie-get.cgi program');


#----------------------------------------------------------------------#
#  4. Retrieve the cookie. Do this by using the cookie method without  #
#     the -value parameter.                                            #
#----------------------------------------------------------------------#


# print $query->h3('The cookie is ...');
$theCookie = $query->cookie('MY_COOKIE');

if(!$theCookie) {
        $theCookie = '';
}

# logit("theCookie = $theCookie\n");
if (index($theCookie, 'ID') != -1) {
        $rval = 1;
}


logit("read_cookie() returning rval = $rval. Having read a value of $theCookie\n");
print $query->end_html;
return($rval);
}
```

l`` But this does not work. I've looked at the samples and it seems that set_cookie script sends the set-cookie before declarng the HTML header, which does not seem correct to me. I call these like this

```
   if (!read_cookie()) {        #get the session id for later use
            $id = $session{_session_id};
    #       print "\n\nSession ID $id\n";
            set_cookie($id);
            return($id);
    }
    I would GREATLY appreciate some guidance here as my frustration level is very high
             $session_id = start_session($cgi);
    }
     and start_sessions calls set_cookie
```

I use use Apache::Session::Store::Postgres; to get a session

Comment: if (!read_cookie()) {        #get the session id for later use
                $id = $session{_session_id};
        #       print "\n\nSession ID $id\n";
                set_cookie($id);
                return($id);
        }
        I would GREATLY appreciate some guidance here as my frustration level is very high
                 $session_id = start_session($cgi);
        }
         and start_sessions calls set_cookie I use use Apache::Session::Store::Postgres;
use Apache::Session::Postgres;
 to get it

Comment: How is this question different than your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63041982/2173773) ?

Comment: I cant figure out how to work this thing. I was just trying to answer a question about hos a variable got set that was posted to the original question

Answer (score 0):

I took your code and cleaned it up so I could read it better and post it with  comments showing my changes.  Some changes were needed for the first subroutine to work properly in very simple unit like tests (set_cookie).  read_cookies() seemed to work after the fixes in set_cookies.  You might still need to tweak it for your needs though.

Hope this helps ya at least a little.

```
#######################################################################
sub set_cookie {
    #------------------------------#
    #  1. Create a new CGI object  #
    #------------------------------#

    my $session = shift;

    my $query;
    my $cookie;
    my $cookie1;
    my $cookie2;
    my $theCookie;
    my $val;
    my $id;


    $query = new CGI;

    logit("Entering set_cookie() called with $session\n");

    #------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
    #  2. Create the desired cookie using the cookie() method.
    #     Do this before calling the header() method, because the cookie must be
    #     incorporated into the HTTP header.
    #
    #------------------------------------------------------------------------------#

    $val = "Session_ID=$session";
    logit("Cookie val set to $val\n");

    $cookie = $query->cookie(-name=>'MY_COOKIE',
                             -value=>$val,
                             -expires=>'+10m',
                             -path=>'/');

    # TOOK OUT THESE 2 COOKIES FOR TESTING AND USED $query->cookie()                        
    #$cookie1 = CGI::Cookie->new(-name=>'ID',
    #                                -expires=>'+10m',
    #                                -value=>123456);

    #$cookie2 = CGI::Cookie->new(-name=>'preferences',
    #                           -value=>{ font => 'Helvetica',
    #                                     size => 12 }
    #                           );

    $cookie1 = $query->cookie(-name=>'ID',
                                    -expires=>'+10m',
                                    -value=>123456);

    $cookie2 = $query->cookie(-name=>'preferences',
                               -value=>{ font => 'Helvetica',
                                         size => 12 }
                               );
    # MISSING $query->
    #print header(-cookie=>[$cookie1,$cookie2]);

    # ADDED $query-> AND ADDED $cookie
    print $query->header(-cookie=>[$cookie,$cookie1,$cookie2]);

    my %cookies = CGI::Cookie->fetch;
    $id = $cookies{'ID'}->value;

    logit("Cookie id set to $id\n");
    logit("Cookie val set to $val\n");

    #--------------------------------------------------------------#
    #  3. Create the HTTP header and print the doctype statement.  #
    #--------------------------------------------------------------#

    # DON'T NEED THIS - $cookie ADDED TO PREVIOUS print header()
    #print $query->header(-cookie => $cookie);

    # Redundant? 
    $theCookie = $query->cookie('MY_COOKIE');

    print $theCookie;
    print $query->end_html;

# ADDED CLOSING BRACKET FOR sub set_cookie
}

#######################################################################
# This seems ok. Tested separately after fixing sub set_cookies
sub read_cookie {
    #------------------------------#
    #  1. Create a new CGI object  #
    #------------------------------#

    my $rval = 0;
    my $theCookie ='';
    my $name;
    my $string;

    my $query = new CGI;

    logit("Entering read_cookie()\n");

    #--------------------------------------------------------------#
    #  2. Create the HTTP header and print the doctype statement.  #
    #--------------------------------------------------------------#

    print $query->header;


    #----------------------------------------------------#
    #  3. Start the HTML doc, and give the page a title  #
    #----------------------------------------------------#

    print $query->start_html('My cookie-get.cgi program');


    #----------------------------------------------------------------------#
    #  4. Retrieve the cookie. Do this by using the cookie method without  #
    #     the -value parameter.                                            #
    #----------------------------------------------------------------------#


    # print $query->h3('The cookie is ...');
    $theCookie = $query->cookie('MY_COOKIE');

    if(!$theCookie) {
            $theCookie = '';
    }

    logit("theCookie = $theCookie\n");

    if (index($theCookie, 'ID') != -1) {
            $rval = 1;
    }


    logit("read_cookie() returning rval = $rval. Having read a value of $theCookie\n");

    print $query->end_html;
    return($rval);
}
#######################################################################
```

Comment: Note: I personally like to use CGI::Simple instead of CGI. Lighter weight without all the HTML formatting.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I believe that I have started to understand my problem a bit better. What I am actually trying to do is the flowing Connect to page, have the page present a request fro login credentials, validate that these are OK, then call and create the session. Then I want to send the browser a cookie with the session ID, so that on the next call, I can determine if a valid loged in session exists.The problem this causes, is that I need too call set_cookie() AFTER having issued a bunch more HTML. This does not seem to work I will check out CGI::Simple, thanks for the recommendation

Comment: Glad to help. Unfortunately you have to set cookies (print the header) before the HTML output.  Sounds like you will need to redesign/rethink your approach. Another thing is don't rely only on browser cookies for valid sessions if you need some sort of secure access (paywall, shopping, etc).

Comment: Thanks, I suspected that. I was hopping I could close out the HTML,set cookies, and restart HTML within the same call to the CGI script, but I have not scudded in getting this work.